# Parse Push Notification comes without Payload

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification

Whenever I try to send data from the cloud I can't access it from the iOS app since the `userInfo` is always a null pointer in either `application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult)` or `application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject: AnyObject])`.
The function is implemented as follows

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
                didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    println("Received Notification")
    handler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)

}
```

The data is being sent like this:

```
Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data: {
        aps: {
            alert: "Test",
            sound: "", 
            "content-available": 1,
            badge: 0
        },
        "p": "12"
    }
}, {
    success: function () {
        response.success("Hello world!");
    },
    error: function (error) {
        response.error(error);
    }
});
```

Is there any way to access the property `p` from the data? Why is `userInfo` always `nil` whereas everywhere else it is said to be pointing at a particular object which could be accessed as an dictionary.

The message itself is being displayed properly and also the badge can be adjusted. If I leave out the `content-available` attribute it also fires a different delegate, so I would say that push is working in general.